# How can I make `text-decoration: underline` looks the same across browsers?

Tags: css, underline

This is the CSS code I use:

```
a {
text-decoration: underline dashed;
}
```

And you can see here that it is displayed differently on different browsers:

On Mozilla:
[image]

On Brave:
[image]

On Chrome:

[image]

How can I make the look consistent?

Comment: You’ve said that the text needs to be wrapped in a div in a comment. However, that needs to be in the original question.

Comment: Yuor question shows single words which are unlikely to be split across lines. In those cases some of the simple answers given will work. However, except in limited cases your problem can't at the moment be solved with just CSS. There is discussion on this for example at https://css-tricks.com/styling-underlines-web/. To get a fully general solution you'd need JS and that would need to alter the HTML.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of underlining text without using `text-decoration: underline`. One way of doing this is with bottom borders.

First make a CSS class for all the text you want to have underlines. Something like this should do:

```
.dashed_underline {
border-bottom: 3px black dashed;
}
```

Then apply this class to your intended paragraph element:

```
<p class="dashed_underline">This text has a dashed underline</p>
```

You should find that the underline now looks the same across web browsers.

Comment: I don't understand why this is a solution - it works in a way if the element doesn't have padding but doesn't look the same as a normal text underline (in terms of how it deals with descenders) and if in the example above the text is more than one line it just 'underlines' the last line.

Comment: @AHaworth It creates an underline kind of thing.

Comment: Agreed, it helps under certain conditions, but it is not a general solution. If for example the text is in an element wider than itself or if there is padding or if there is more than one line. Perhaps these limitations could be listed in your answer so people know what part of the problem it is solving and they can judge whether it is suitable for them.

Answer (score 0):

Well since every browser has it's own unique way of displaying HTML and CSS you can use something like this

```css
.dash.underline {
  text-decoration: none;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #000 75%, transparent 75%);
  background-position: 0 1.04em;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: 8px 3px;
}
```

```html
<p class="dash underline">See it works!</p>
```

You can read Why does your text decoration or any other stuff looks different from browsers to browsers here at [webfx.com](https://www.webfx.com/internet-marketing/why-does-your-website-look-different-in-different-browsers.html)

You can also checkout [Underline.js](https://underlinejs.wentin.net/) they are doing some pretty good job just for underlines and stuff. [Underline.js GitHub](https://github.com/wentin/underlineJS)

Comment: The problem with border-bottom is that then I need to wrap the text in one more div (if not, any text that has padding will not show the bottom border right under the text). Ideally I'd like to avoid adding another div

Comment: This solution (which has the merit of not requiring a border bottom but has several other problems) does not work if the text wraps over more than one line, or if there is padding or if the text is in an element much wider than itelf. It is, sadly, not a general solution.

Answer (score 0):

**You can use the code below**

```
a
{
text-decoration-thickness: 2px;
}
```